# Algorithm : finding nearby value the fastest way

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, optimization

I have an array of sorted numbers, and a starting value. For the sake of simplicity, let's say the array has values from 1 to 20, and the starting value is 10.

The value to find can change every 5 seconds, based on user input. It can either increase or decrease and it always keeps in the range of values of the table.

The only thing I cannot know is whether the value is increasing or decreasing. I have come up with the (very) simple algorithm below.

Can you think of a way to improve it ?
Ideally, I think the best approach would be to run the two for loops simultaneously and return when value is found... Using workers for example ?
In my example, the "going down" for loops is exhausted before "going up" starts running. Which, idealy, shouldn't happen, since I'm trying to spread tries -1/+1 each time.

Btw : the reason why I'm trying to do this is because I have to run quite heavy functions in the for loops. The code is running in node.js context.

[Here's a JSFiddle and the code below](https://jsfiddle.net/Pisha/r54x5fja/5/)

```
const attempts = document.getElementById('attempts');
let attemptsCount = Number(attempts.textContent);
const lastValue = 10;
const valueToFind = 16; //this must be found in the least possible number of attempts
const table = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

const lookup = () => {
    for (var i = lastValue; i > 0; i--) {
    if (table[i] == valueToFind) {
        alert('Found going down');
      return;
    } else {
    attemptsCount++;
    attempts.textContent = attemptsCount;
    }
  }

  for (var i = lastValue; i < table[table.length-1]; i++) {
    if (table[i] == valueToFind) {
        alert('Found going up');
      return;
    } else {
    attemptsCount++;
    attempts.textContent = attemptsCount;
    }
  }
}

//find new value
lookup();
```

Comment: you could use a binary search.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your problem. It sounds as though you have a listed of sorted numbers and every 5 seconds you need to find the closest number in your list to some target value. If the target values are chosen independently then there is no way to improve on a simple binary search, which finds the answer in _O(lg(N))_ time.

Comment: Wish I could make it all clearer, but I guess I'm not that good of a describer, and it does lack context. That being said, your understanding is correct and answer helpful.

Comment: Can the value increase in one time period, and then decrease the next time period? Is there a limit to the value delta? That is, could it go from 19 to 1 in a single 5-second period?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, no and yep ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, each `for` loop you have runs async from one another...so one side will always finish before the other side starts...which is not ideal.

Remember that `for` loops are set up to initialize, check if bool statement = true, and set next step...so like if statements, you can implement multiple statements in each scenario.

Reducing the loop attempts can be simple as doing it at the same time:

```
const lookup = () => {
    for (var up = lastValue, down = lastValue-1; up < table[table.length-1] || down > 0; up++, down--) {
    if (up < table[table.length-1] && table[up] == valueToFind) {
        alert('Found going up');
      return;
    } else if (down > 0 && table[down] == valueToFind) {
        alert('Found going down');
      return;
    } else {
        attemptsCount++;
        attempts.textContent = attemptsCount;
    }
  }
```

[Your JSFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/r54x5fja/6/)

Comment: Damn. And it was here all along, I'd never quite seen it that way -- for loops being there only to set a flag. Thanks, I think it'll do it.